# elasticsearch сортировка по вхождению

Tags: elasticsearch

Есть поиск через elasticsearch, и есть 20 товаров, у всех есть в названии слово 'Апельсин', но у некоторых это слово в конце предложения, но при выдаче я получаю их в начале. Как сделать так, чтобы ES выдавал вначале результат с более ранним вхождением слова?

Comment: `ORDER BY INSTR(field, word)`

Comment: @Akina тут нет никакого отношения к sql запросам